# AlarmManager Dilemma for Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to set a repeating alarm monthly;  but my app resets the alarm everytime it boots up.  So is it bad practice to do it this way rather than setting a repeating alarm?

(The Alarm is set for a specific day of the month.  (e.g. The 8th, 16th, 21st, etc).  So if it is past that day, it simply +1's on the total the current month.)

I also run a service on boot up to set any alarms so even if they don't go into the app for a month, it will be reset again.

Again, is this the best way of doing this or is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it bad practice to do it this way rather than setting a repeating alarm?

If it works for you, it is probably fine.

> I also run a service on boot up to set any alarms so even if they don't go into the app for a month, it will be reset again.

That is a little odd. Getting control at boot time to re-establish alarms is fine, but you should not need a service for that.

Comment: I have heard services may be a battery issue.  Is there a better way of doing this?  The service basically triggers the AlarmMaanger code again.  (It does work, I just rather not waste resources).

Comment: @KickingLettuce: Set your next alarm when your app starts, or at least the first time the app starts. Also set your next alarm on a reboot (via a simple `BroadcastReceiver`), since a reboot wipes out the `AlarmManager` schedule. Nothing else is needed. When the alarm goes off, set your next alarm. It does not matter whether the user goes into your activity or not once the first alarm is scheduled -- each alarm schedules the next.